# Android Cross-domain error in local server

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax, cordova

I am using phoneGap-2.9.0

I can't access my `api.php` page in local server. i am getting `error!` alert.

Please check my code:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerForm').submit(function(){ 
        var postData = $(this).serialize();
        var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: formUrl,
            dataType : 'json',
            data: postData,         
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error!');
            }
        }); 


        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" method="post" action="http://localhost/android/REST_API/api.php">
        <label>First Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
        <label>Last Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
</form>
```

**api.php**

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); echo "true"; ?>
```

Above code i am running in browser it working fine. But it is not working in device emulator. In emulator if i am using `http://www.raddyx.in/api.php` instead of `http://localhost/android/REST_API/api.php` i am gettng `true`.

Please me and let me know the problem.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are not handling the preflight requiest (OPTION) on your server. -->http://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=754

Comment: You cannot use `localhost`, try using the IP Address instead

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yes i am using `127.0.0.1` it also not working.

Comment: @h3li0s please explain me regarding your (OPTION)

Comment: After reading through your edited question, this doesn't seem to be a prefligth issue. This seems to be some issue with the emulator. You could try to capture the http request sent by the emulator to the server, to compare with the http request sent by your browser.

Comment: Cordova is not a php server. When you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 you're targeting your phone or emulator or whatever runs the app, not your pc or a server. You have to use the url of a real server.

Comment: I am using `*` for access all domain. Still not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why this is happening but my money is on the fact that its an emulator, if you deploy it to a physical device it should work the same as in a desktop browser, If you try JSONP instead of JSON then your issue should be resolved on the emulator as this sidesteps any cross domain security breach the emulator may think is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#registerForm').submit(function(){ 
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: formUrl,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        data: postData,         
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error!');
        }
    }); 


    return false; 
}); 
});
```

Comment: hello ` $res['result']='success'; echo json_encode($res);` not working when i am using `jsonp` instead of `json` Please help me.